# CSS gradient colour stops from end in pixels

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm working on a HTML/CSS/JS project where the app is a fixed size and elements must be positioned precisely, based on the designs. Because the window size is fixed, I can easily work with pixel dimensions in CSS and not worry about resizing the browser.  I also have the luxury of not worrying about IE or Opera: the app must work in webkit and firefox only.

In a few places, I need to have a gradient background going over specific number of pixels.  This would be easily accomplished with something like

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #666666, #000000 60px);
```

(and its `-webkit-` and `-moz-` counterparts.)  This does the trick for most elements.  However there are a couple where I need to have the top and bottom pixel positions for colour stops.  If these were percentage points, then it could be done with something like:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #666666, black 60px, transparent 60px, transparent 90%, black 90%, #666666);
```

(from grey to black over 60px, then transparent and then black to grey over the last 10%). However I need to accomplish the same with pixels, as the element in question is sized differently at different times.  I'd like to avoid having to use JS to re-apply the gradient at different dynamically calculated percentage points if needed.

So, my question: is there a way to specify a colour stop *x* **pixels** (not percentage) from the end?

Answer (score 7):

I just came over this via search engine, i think the best solution was already given by vals with using **multiple background images** - but instead of using `background-size` and `background-position` i think it's a lot more flexible and stable to use **alpha colors** here (with `rgba()`), like in the example below:

```
background-image:
    /* top gradient - pixels fixed */
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(128,128,128) 0px,rgba(128,128,128,0) 16px), 
    /* bottom gradient - pixels fixed */
    linear-gradient(to top, rgb(128,128,128) 0px, rgba(128,128,128,0) 16px),  
    /* background gradient - relative */
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 0%, #ccc 100%) ;
```

This gives me exactly the behaviour I was initially searching for. :)

Demo: http://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/LVBxgQ

Comment: This is clever! It's too bad we can't use a negative value or something like "right 16px" like we can for positioning regular background images.

Answer (score 2):

It works with `calc()`, but unfortunately not in MS browsers:

First row of each pairs has the solution with 2 background stacked, 2nd row has calc in use. Does not work with Internet Explorer and Edge browsers.

```css
div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: sweep 5s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  will-change: width;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green 100px, transparent 101px), linear-gradient(to left, red, green 100px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green 100px, green calc(100% - 100px), red);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(n+3) {
  width: 300px;
}

div:nth-child(n+5) {
  width: 400px;
}

div:nth-child(n+7) {
  width: 500px;
}

div:nth-child(n+9) {
  width: 600px;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  100% {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div> 200 </div>
<div></div>
<div> 300 </div>
<div></div>
<div> 400 </div>
<div></div>
<div> 500 </div>
<div></div>
<div> 600 </div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, but overlaying 2 objects, one with opaque pixels from bottom and the other with pixels from top, would still avoid using JS

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #666666, black 60px, transparent 60px);
}
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666, black 60px, transparent 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line of the previous answer from po228, but in the same element background.

Set 2 different gradients, one starting from top and the other from bottom

```css
.test {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 10px, white 10px),
      linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 10px, white 10px);
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center, top center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```